# Generating signed Bundle requires you to update the Android Gradle plugin to version 3.2.0 or higher

Tags: android, bundle

I know this question has been answered multiple times but none of the solutions are working for me. I have updated the build.gradle files
[image]

When I try to run the update by command line
[image]

This is the file structure in my project

[image]

How do I get this to work? I am trying to build an signed bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Build -> Flutter -> Build App Bundle*** instead of ***Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK***